# mysql select 2 row from each group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

i have 2 table with this structure

**Products**

```
id       title
-----------------
1       sample 1
2       sample 2
3       sample 3
4       sample 4
5       sample 5
6       sample 6
```

**gallery**

```
id       typeid       name
-------------------------------

1          1         sample for 1
2          1         sample for 1
3          1         sample for 1
4          2         sample for 2
5          2         sample for 2
7          2         sample for 2
8          3         sample for 3
9          3         sample for 3
10         3         sample for 3
11         4         sample for 4
12         4         sample for 4
13         5         sample for 5
14         5         sample for 5
```

**and iwant this for lists of id eg(1,2,3)**

```
id      typeid       name
---------------------

1      1          sample for 1
1      2          sample for 1
2      4          sample for 2
2      5          sample for 2
3      8          sample for 3
3      9          sample for 3
```

**here is my query**

```
 select p.*,g.* from products p inner join gallery g ON p.id=g.typeid where p.id in (3,4,5) group by typeid
```

**here is real structure [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f8a2/5)**

Comment: Where is your query? Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand your example. How is `typeid = 2` related to `sample for 1`?

Comment: How is the `products` table being used in this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, g.typeid, g.id, g.title
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gallery a
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery b WHERE b.title = a.title AND b.id >= a.id) <= 2
           ) g ON p.id = g.typeid 
WHERE p.id in (3,4,5)
```

**EDIT:**

Try this [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f8a2/8)

```
SELECT p.id, g.typeid, g.id, g.name
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gallery a
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery b WHERE b.typeid = a.typeid AND b.id >= a.id) <= 2
           ) g ON p.id = g.typeid 
WHERE p.id in (3,4,5) order by g.id asc
```

So basically this part

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery b WHERE b.title = a.title AND b.id >= a.id) <= 2
```

is used to replace `group by typeid`

Comment: Ok let me take a look

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.id,p.title, g.typeid, g.id, g.name
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gallery a
            WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery b WHERE b.typeid = a.typeid AND b.id >= a.id)
```

**please try this**