# Select the first 3 occurrences of each ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
ID | date   
1   | 2016-01-01   
1   | 2016-01-02   
1   | 2016-02-01   
1   | 2016-03-01  
1   | 2016-03-11   
2   | 2016-01-01   
2   | 2016-01-03   
2   | 2016-01-05   
2   | 2016-02-01   
2   | 2016-03-01   
3   | 2016-01-03   
3   | 2016-01-04   
3   | 2016-01-05   
3   | 2016-01-06
```

I need the query to return the first 3 dates from each ID, the result should be:

```
ID | date   
1   | 2016-01-01   
1   | 2016-01-02   
1   | 2016-02-01   
2   | 2016-01-01   
2   | 2016-01-03   
2   | 2016-01-05   
3   | 2016-01-03   
3   | 2016-01-04   
3   | 2016-01-05
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select 2 row from each group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283889/mysql-select-2-row-from-each-group-by)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT ID, `date`
FROM (
  SELECT ID, `date`,
         @rn := IF(@id = ID, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@id := ID, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY ID, `date`) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @ekaizawa Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.